# Unable to connect to database using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Windows Native Authentication

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-authentication, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am having trouble connecting to an Oracle database using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Windows Native Authentication.

I am developing on a workstation from which I am able to connect to the same database using NTS via the PL/SQL Developer, and via C# code using non-managed Oracle.DataAccess. This leads me to I believe that there is nothing fundamentally wrong with either the database, workstation or the account. Now I am trying to evaluate if it's possible to switch to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess in our solution.

I've tried the following so far:

- Created a new blank project OracleManagedAccessTest
- Under references added the NuGet package Oracle.ManagedAccessTest v19.3.1 (the latest at the time of writing)
- Update the <dataSource> tag in the App.config to match the entry in the tnsnames.ora (to make the C# project self-contained and not relying on external component)
- Added <setting name="sqlnet.authentication_services" value="NTS"/> tag under <oracle.manageddataaccess.client><version number="*"><settings> in the App.config

I am using the following minimal code to test the connection:

```
try
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=EDBDEVD;User Id=/;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The attempt to connect fails with the following error: "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

This looks almost like too simple of a problem, yet I can't seem to resolve it, or find a workable solution online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/InstallManagedConfig.html#GUID-29A85CBD-948D-4C9F-A89D-A96A99EFF2D7)? Perhaps you have to set `<setting name="sqlnet.authentication_services" value="(NTS)"/>` It also says *The NTS external authentication methodology is only supported on a **Windows-based** client and **server**.*

Comment: I did and I did (see the last point under "I've tried the following so far:"). Tried both with and without brackets, with the same result. Without the setting it actually tries to connect using Kerberos, which tells me the setting has some effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#

conn.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = "select department_name from departments where department_id = 10"; cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

dr.Read();

label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
```

see also: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm